# Makefile: prevent infinite pattern recursion

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I thought this is quite simple

```
%.png: ../figs/%.png
        convert $? -resize '40%' $@
```

That is, I want to generate an image in this directory from the corresponding image in "../figs/" .

But, the above leads to an infinite chain of dependencies because `../figs/foo.png` matches `%.png` and therefore make tries to check `../figs/../figs/foo.png`, which matches `%.png` and therefore make tries to . . .
Eventually, make stops with "File name too long".

I must be missing something.  What is a clean solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kill the chain with an empty rule

```
%.png: ../figs/%.png
    convert $? -resize '40%' $@

../figs/%.png: ;
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect.  Interestingly, GNU Make 3.81 that comes with Mac OS X still generates an infinite chain with your code, whereas GNU Make 4.2.1 which I separately installed does not.  Does that mean that this problem was solved only recently?

Comment: Looks like pattern rules were switched to shortest stem order in [3.82](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS), you can work around this in 3.81 by putting the empty rule before the other one.

Answer (score 4):

All the answers above are quite interesting. However, I'll like to mention the terminal rule solution:

```
%.png:: ../figs/%.png
    convert $? -resize '40%' $@
```

By changing to a double colon `::`, we then mark the prerequisites [terminal](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html):

> One choice is to mark the *match-anything rule* as terminal by defining it with a double colon. **When a rule is terminal, it does not apply unless its prerequisites actually exist.** Prerequisites that could be made with other implicit rules are not good enough. In other words, no further chaining is allowed beyond a terminal rule.

*Note: only suitable for match-anything rules.*

- [What are double-colon rules in a Makefile for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891097/what-are-double-colon-rules-in-a-makefile-for)
- [GNU make seems to ignore non-terminal match-anything rules for intermediate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481042/gnu-make-seems-to-ignore-non-terminal-match-anything-rules-for-intermediate-file)

Answer (score 1):

[user657267](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657267/user657267)'s solution is perfect. Another option is to use static pattern rules:

```
PNGS    := $(patsubst ../figs/%.png,%.png,$(wildcard ../figs/*.png))

all: $(PNGS)

$(PNGS): %.png: ../figs/%.png
    convert $< -resize '40%' $@

clean:
    rm -f $(PNGS)
```

Computing the list of all targets from the list of all prerequisites has several nice side effects, like the prossibility of adding the `all` and `clean` targets, for instance.

Comment: Thanks!  I already use a list of targets like your PNGS, but I didn't know that you can use the list to limit the application of the pattern (your 3rd non-empty line, with two colons).  By the way, I use `$(notdir . . .)` function instead of `patsubst`.